# Short answers are floating right in Safari 10.1.2

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Short answers aren't rendering correctly in Safari 10.1.2. *I haven't tested other versions of Safari.*

---

## [Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38785989/1599191)

[image: Screenshot of answer]

Comment: I think that's just how they're Mac-relevant answers obvious to Mac users ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed in the next build.

Safari 10 still needs a vendor prefix for `max-content`.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Can confirm that I do not see the problem in Safari 11.

Comment: Was this answer intentionally kept short [in order to demonstrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTn01.png)? :)

Comment: @JoshCaswell You tell me -- what does it look like now? :)